# How to use an accesskey on a WPF Button with a custom ContentTemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, access-keys

**Scenario:**

Currently I have this XAML code:

```
<Button Content="_Cancel" IsCancel="True" Command="{Binding Path=CancelCommand}" Margin="5">
   <Button.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Margin="10,0,10,0" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Obviously the accesskey (the 'c' key: _Cancel) doesn't work in combination with the TextBlock. I actually think the TextBlock should be a ContentPresenter (below), but this crashes my Visual Studio 2010 instance every time.

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="10,0,10,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
```

**Question:**

- What's the best solution to use accesskeys on a WPF Button with a ContentTemplate?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `TextBlock` use `AccessText` thus:

```
<Button Content="_Cancel" IsCancel="True" Command="{Binding Path=CancelCommand}" Margin="5">
   <Button.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <AccessText Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

PS. `ContentPresenter` should be used inside a `ControlTemplate` to display content according to a `DataTemplate`. If you use it within a `DataTemplate` it causes infinite recursion as the `DataTemplate` is invoked over and over again.