# How to access buttons in diffrent pages in windowsphone apps

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a question like this, I have two pages and have one button in each page, like this mainpage.xaml and second page.xaml, my button in mainpage was disabled with this code: `<Button  Name="one" IsEnabled="False" Content="Button"  />`.
Now I want to enable this button with another button that placed in second page.xaml, how I can access the button in mainpage.xaml and make it enable?

I can't access `one.isenabled=true` in second page, what can I do?

Comment: What does your (relevant) code look like? What efforts have you made so far, where have those efforts gone wrong (what did they do that they shouldn't, what didn't they do that they should)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use an accesskey on a WPF Button with a custom ContentTemplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416303/how-to-use-an-accesskey-on-a-wpf-button-with-a-custom-contenttemplate)

Comment: i want to use this feature in my app, but i didnt know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way of doing that.

You can have a global varible to read value from & set enabled/disabled accordingly, send data through URIs (Navigation Contexts) etc. There can be many other solutions too.

At the worst case, take reference variable of the button in code-behind of MainPage.xaml (`public static Button b=one;`) & access it from another page (`MainPage.b.isEnabled=true;`). Still, I **don't** recommend this.