# Using underscores in WPF menu items when binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've created a Recent Files menu item to which I bind a collection of recent file view models.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Recent Files" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}" Command="{x:Static pm:MainWindow.RecentFileListCommand}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{x:Static pm:MainWindow.RecentFileOpenCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding FilePath}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

I want the list numbered, and I want the numbers to be used as the shortcut (exactly how Visual Studio does it). My view models have a Number field and Name field. I override the ToString() method to return a header including the underscore:

```
return string.Format("_{0} {1}", Number, FilePath);
```

However, when bound, the underscore is seen as a literal and displays as part of the header text (not the shortcut). I also tried using HeaderStringFormat without luck:How can I get WPF to see the underscore as the shortcut and not a literal string?

Comment: You might try giving the menuitem a ContentTemplate with an `AccessText` control in it, [as in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7416523/424129) (that's for a button, but MenuItem as a ContentTemplate property too -- inherited from the same ancestor class IIRC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try to return an `AccessText`, though it might break separation of concerns.

As mentioned by [Matthew Whited](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89586/matthew-whited), a cleaner way would be to return the string only and use a converter to turn it into an `AccessText`. Alternatively use the [`HeaderTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.headertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) and create it there.

Comment: If you just want to return a string from the view model couldn't you just use a TypeConverter to change to an `AccessText`?

Comment: I think you'd want a *value converter*, but yes, that'd probably work just fine.

Comment: yeah... i was trying to fix my comment but ran out of time :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was already using a ValueConverter in order to truncate file paths with ellipsis. Instead of returning a string, I changed it to return AccessText and now it works.