# Is it possible to assign AccessText to a WPF Button programmatically after modifying the Button's style?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I've overridden my `Button` style in my application, which seemingly removed the ability for me to use `Button.Content` with an `_` to assign an access key, therefore leaving me with the only option of use `AccessText`. I viewed a few questions which dealt with how to make a Button have an access key again, such as [How to use an accesskey on a WPF Button with a custom ContentTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416303/how-to-use-an-accesskey-on-a-wpf-button-with-a-custom-contenttemplate), which solved my issue up until now.

I have a Window where the `Button`'s `Content` was set programmatically, depending on how you got to that Window.

This is how I was assigning an access key before:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Text="_Hello" />
```

and it worked just fine, properly displaying an underlined `H` in `Hello`. Since changing the style, it no longer works that way.

This is how `AccessText` is normally done:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1">
    <AccessText>_Hello</AccessText>
</Button>
```

which shows up with the `H` in `Hello` underlined, regardless of custom styles.

Unfortunately, the only Property I can find which allows you to modify what a button displays is `Content`, and when I try to assign `Button.Content` like so:

```
Button1.Content = "_Goodbye";
```

it displays `_Goodbye` instead of treating it like an access key like it did before I applied my custom style. The `G` in `Goodbye` is not underlined, and unable to be used as an access key.

Therefore, my question is: Is it possible to assign AccessText to a WPF Button programmatically after modifying the Button's style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the content of the `Button` with an `AccessText` object and set its `Text` property.

```
Button1.Content = new AccessText
{
    Text = "_Goodbye",
};
```